# How to add a UIView on top of an OpenGL game (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, opengl-es, flixel

I have downloaded this source from here: https://github.com/ericjohnson/canabalt-ios
It is the source code of the Canabalt game for iOS

The game is built on the [Flixel](https://github.com/ericjohnson/canabalt-ios/tree/master/flixel-ios) engine.

I wanted to achieve a simple thing. I want to add a UIView to one of the in-game screens. How can I achieve that?

I have tried doing stuff like:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 120)];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self add:myView];
```

This, of course, throws an error saying that: *`Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIView \*' to parameter of type 'FlxObject \*'`*

I cannot find any way to "convert" a `UIView` to `FlxObject`. It feels like a simple requirement, but the solution has eluded me so far. I have tried reading through this Flixel library to figure out some way to do this, but found nothing.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add your view directly to the top window

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: It's okay as long as you don't need to handle orientation changes, as you'll have to manage these your self.